# Tomcat 9 - long https request

Tags: ssl, openssl, tomcat9

I am sending a request that includes media and has a contentLength of about 200k.
It works fine when sending to the non-SSL port but when sending to the SSL port
the ByteBuffer of the request's Reader does not contain all the request.
I think it has to do with the appReadBufSize setting.

A shorter, 255-byte SSL request works fine - so the problem is not with SSL
but has to do with the length.

I suppose it should be possible to pass long SSL requests to Tomcat but did not
find  any reference about the difference between SSL and non-SSL handling of long requests. The connector uses openssl.

server.xml connector definitions:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" />

  <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           connectionTimeout="20000" maxPostSize="-1"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" sslProtocol="TLS"
           scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false"
           ... SSL keystore definitions/>
```

Please advise,
Many thanks,
Yuval

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that there was indeed a bug in Tomcat:
http://tomcat.10.x6.nabble.com/Bug-64486-New-Receiving-null-empty-request-body-when-SSL-enabled-td5099846.html

I was running Tomcat 9.0.31 under Ubunto 20. The problem disappeared when upgrading to Tomcat 9.0.37 (manual install).